# Querying and inserting/deleting data simultaneously in SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Is is possible to insert/delete/update a row in my SQLite table while reading the data from the same table. As shown below, I am querying the database by running a raw query. While I am looping through the cursor, I want to manipulate the data within the same table in the same loop.

```
 Cursor c = mySqldb.rawQuery("select * from tablename", null);
 while(!c.isLast){
  if(condition){
     //delete the row
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please brief what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @GrIsHu Hope the question is a bit clear now

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing stopping you from doing `mySqldb.delete(...)` inside the `if` block. But, if the condition is something that SQLite can understand, you should just use one delete statement that affects multiple rows, e.g. "DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [condition]".